# HTML5 Video won't display if Iphone is turned horizontally

Tags: html, css, iphone, video, html5-video

I am using HTML5 code for displaying video on my website, it works perfectly on desktop PC and on non "apple" phones, but on Iphones, it's acting strange.

**HTML code for video.** So basically I have 2 videos, one for desktop and one for mobile, the mobile is set on display none on desktop and opposite on mobile devices.

```
<section class="video">
  <video class="video-fluid" controls playsinline width="100%" >
  <source id="dekstop_video" src="/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/Video/onas_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <video class="video-fluid" controls="true" playsinline preload="metadata" width="100%" >
  <source id="mobile_video" src="/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/Video/onas_mobilna.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</section>
```

Let me explain now how video is acting on iphone. When I land on the page, the video is displayed like this (watch image)--> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uutpz.jpg); it has only the play button without borders, but that is not the case,later I'll set the thumbnail picture over the video.

The funny thing happens, when the video starts playing in full screen mode (vertically) it's like that --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv2D0.jpg), and then when I flip, phone horizontally, the video "picutre is gone", display is black, but the video is still playing in the background aswell as sound.

I have tried with adding the HTML code into video, such as: "playsinline", "controls='true'", "preload='metadata'".

**With CSS I have tried:**

```
video{
object-fit:fill;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #dekstop_video{
   
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #mobile_video {
   
   width:100%; 
    height: 100%;

    padding:0
  }
}
```

If anyone have ever dealt with this problem, please help me out, because I really can't figure it out why it's acting this way.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `webkit-playsinline` if your using ios10 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your problem.. but something you should fix:

When you use display:none to hide the desktop video on mobile, that does not mean "download:none." CSS is parsed AFTER downloads are started. Your code will download 2 videos for all users (which is the opposite of what you are trying to do)

Want to see it in action?  https://www.trumptowerny.com/

[image: screenshot from devtools showing 2 video downloads]

Having 2 video tags ensures that the browser will request both "onas_video.mp4" and "onas_mobilna.mp4" Better to use JavaScript to insert the source - based on the screen size (and the you just need one video tag)